# A mystery of shrinking image in android

Tags: android, size, drawable

There is an image with height 80 and width 120px behind an url. So let me fetch it:

```
private InputStream fetch(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException 
{
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    return response.getEntity().getContent();
}
```

I'm getting the InputStream I want and drawable:

```
InputStream is = fetch(url);
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "");

int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
```

And suddenly my image is 80x53 px. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to convince my application to keep original size of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rly don't know how to solve your problem using a Drawable object, but if you can try to do this with a Bitmap.
As used on my own projects, I never had this problem with the images size:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```